# Converting OutputStream into PipedOutputstream

Tags: java, casting, stream, inputstream, outputstream

In Java have some existing code in Function A that returns an OutputStream, but I'd like it to return a PipedOutputStream that I can use with a PipedInputStream like so:

`this.inputStream = new PipedInputStream(this.outputStream);`

Does casting an OutputStream to a PipedInputStream work, or do I need to begin with a fresh new PipedOutputStream and repeat all the logic there?

More Code:

my PipedInputStream will be transferring data to s3 like this:

`tm.upload(bucketName, objectKey, this.inputStream, objectMetadata);`

(tm is the TransferManager)

and the PipedOutputStream will be with a Writer that writes to files.

```
OutputStream out = (encryptionKeyId != null) ?
                    pgpService.buildPgpOutputStream(this.outputStream, encryptionKeyId) :
                    this.outputStream;
            return toBufferedWriter(out);
```

So in the switch above, when `out` is `this.outputStream;`, it's working fine. because it's PipedOutputStream. but `pgpService.buildPgpOutputStream(this.outputStream, encryptionKeyId)` returns an OutputStream, not a Piped one, so not sure what to do.

Comment: No, casting will not work. Can you edit the question to add the relevant parts of the code, to get a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Joni I've added some, just for clarification - thanks.

Comment: you have access to pgpService code ? You can change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

The `bufferedWriter` that you build, eventually writes to `this.outputStream` which is your piped output stream. You don't need to cast it or do anything with it - you already have a reference to both ends of the pipe in the instance variables of your class. I'm assuming your code looks like the following.

```
this.outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
this.inputStream = new PipedInputStream(this.outputStream);
OutputStream out = (encryptionKeyId != null) ?
                    pgpService.buildPgpOutputStream(this.outputStream, encryptionKeyId) :
                    this.outputStream;
return toBufferedWriter(out);
```

Comment: That's exactly my code - and great point, that it consumes a PipedOutputStream as a parameter, and so it should have the right reference in the end anyways and not have any issues technically. Thank you.